# Find records using having clause

Tags: sql, database

I would like to retrieve all records having the most recent modification time.
For example, taking this table:

```
|page_url|last_modified|
---------
|abc.com |2010-10-01 10:00:00|
|xyz.com |2010-10-04 12:10:00|
|xyz.com |2010-10-04 12:00:00|
|xyz.com |2010-10-04 10:00:00|
|abc.com |2010-10-01 08:00:00|
```

And output should contain following data:

```
|page_url|last_modified|
---------
|abc.com |2010-10-01 10:00:00|
|xyz.com |2010-10-04 12:10:00|
```

I have tried using having clause like below but not working for me :(

```
SELECT page_url, last_modified 
FROM
my_table
HAVING MAX(last_modified);
```

Edit 1 : I am having 25 fields in my table to use. But, I guess I can't apply group by for all. What to do now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `HAVING` on this, only `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT page_url, MAX(last_modified) 
FROM my_table
GROUP BY page_url
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    my_table a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT page_url, MAX(last_modified) recentDate
            FROM my_table
            GROUP BY page_url
        ) b ON a.page_url = b.page_url AND
                a.last_modified = b.recentDate
```

Comment: I am having 25 fields in my table to use. But, I guess I can't apply group by for all. What to do now?

Comment: @SaurabhSaxena ok i got you, try my updated answer. you need to get the latest date first in a subquery and join it to the original table itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `group by` and `max()` in `select` statement

```
SELECT page_url, max(last_modified) 
FROM  my_table
group by page_url
```

More information:

- [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
- [MAX](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp)
- [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an RDBMS which has tuple-capable `IN` like Postgresql, MySql and Oracle. You can use the following approach.

So let's say you already have existing view like this:

```
create view page_latest as

SELECT page_url, MAX(last_modified) recentDate
FROM tbl
GROUP BY page_url;


select * from page_latest;
```

Output...

```
| PAGE_URL |                     RECENTDATE |
---------------------------------------------
|  abc.com | October, 01 2010 10:00:00+0000 |
|  xyz.com | October, 04 2010 12:10:00+0000 |
```

...based on this data:

```
| PAGE_URL |                  LAST_MODIFIED |            MESSAGE |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|  abc.com | October, 01 2010 10:00:00+0000 |           no alarm |
|  xyz.com | October, 04 2010 12:10:00+0000 |       no surprises |
|  xyz.com | October, 04 2010 12:00:00+0000 | fake plastic trees |
|  xyz.com | October, 04 2010 10:00:00+0000 |              creep |
|  abc.com | October, 01 2010 08:00:00+0000 |         thom yorke |
```

You can find all latest messages by re-using the above view with tuple-capable IN of aforementioned RDBMSes: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8193/2

```
select * 
from tbl
where (page_url,last_modified) in (select page_url, recentDate from page_latest);
```

Output:

```
| PAGE_URL |                  LAST_MODIFIED |      MESSAGE |
------------------------------------------------------------
|  abc.com | October, 01 2010 10:00:00+0000 |     no alarm |
|  xyz.com | October, 04 2010 12:10:00+0000 | no surprises |
```

Not only the query is shorter, it's easier to read. Though if you don't have a view lying around, you can inline a "view" in your query: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8193/5

```
select * 
from tbl
where (page_url,last_modified) in

  (SELECT page_url, MAX(last_modified) recentDate
   FROM tbl
   GROUP BY page_url);
```

This answer doesn't work in Sql Server. There are only few database that doesn't support tuple-capable `IN`, unfortunately Sql Server is one of them

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT z.page_url,z.last_modified 
FROM (SELECT page_url, MAX(last_modified) 
      FROM my_table 
      GROUP BY page_url) as z 
ORDER BY z.page_url
```

Answer (score 0):

How about these-

```
    SELECT   page_url,last_modified,other field
    FROM my_table
    ORDER BY page_url,last_modified
```

OR

```
   SELECT  distinct page_url,last_modified,other field
   FROM my_table
   ORDER BY page_url,last_modified
```